# How to align elements to Bootstrap grid?

Tags: alignment, grids, layout, bootstrap

Sorry for the beginner question, but I'm having a hard time trying to figure this out. I'm using a grid for a Bootstrap design but my problem is how do I align elements to the grid? See my image for better explanation:

[image]

Should I consider the alignment of element 1 or 2 as the outer limit?

Another issue I face is I can align text and images to the grid, but what if text is inside a (visible) box? Should I align content to the grid or the outer box? If I align content, I face the issue seen in 4 but if I align the outer box, then I lose the grid for the content (although I think this is the correct way).  How should I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Bootstrap Documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic) doesn't seem to have a great example for this as far as I can tell.

I set up [an example](http://codepen.io/bitHero/full/dGGEvq/) to try to visualize what Bootstrap does with the columns (I added your guide lines for comparision).

[image]

The gist of it is, the *column div* is full width (Box #4) but has left and right padding (15px) so the content of the column will be padded by that much at least. In my example I also added top and bottom padding (not standard) to make it more readable, the bootstrap documentation does this as well. This means your content will end up looking like Box #3.

So if you have content with backgrounds inside the column it will look like Box #3. If your columns have backgrounds they will look like Box #4.